# how to sum all the consummations?

Tags: django

I already calculate, the total of one consummation, now i just want to sum all the consumations

```
class Consommation(models.Model):
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food)
    consomme_le = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    vipcustomer = models.ForeignKey(VipCustomer, models.CASCADE, null=True, 
    blank=True, verbose_name='Client prestigieux', 
    related_name='vip_consommations')
```

> to calculate one consummation:

```
def total(self):
     return self.food.aggregate(total=Sum('price'))['total']
```

> Food class :

```
class Food(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Mon menu')
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Prix')
    category = models.ForeignKey(FoodCategory, models.CASCADE, 
    verbose_name="Categorie")
```

> vipcustomer class:

```
class VipCustomer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Prénom')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nom')
    matricule = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Matricule', 
    default=0)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Adresse', 
    blank=True)
    telephone = PhoneField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='La société')
    service = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Service', 
    null=True, blank=True)
    numero_badge = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Numero du badge', 
    null=True, blank=True)
```

My goal is to calculate the total of all the consummations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `VipCustomer`s, you can query with:

```
my_vip_customer.vip_consommations.aggregate(
    total=Sum('food__price')
)['total']
```

We thus aggregate over the set of *related* `Consommation`s, and we then aggregate over all the related `Food`s of these `Consommation`s, and their corresponding `price`.

If there are no related `Consommation`s, or no related `Food`s of these `Consommation`s, then the sum will return `None`, instead of `0`. We can add `or 0` to convert a `None` to an `0` here:

```
my_vip_customer.vip_consommations.aggregate(
    total=Sum('food__price')
)['total'] or 0
```

or for all `Customer`s, we can annotate this with:

```
VipCustomer.objects.annotate(
    total=Sum('vip_consommations__food__price')
)
```

Here the `VipCustomer`s that arise from this, will have an extra attribute `.total` that contains the sum of the `price`s of the related `Food`s of the related `Consommation`s.

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem for your quick response, it worked!

Comment: I have forgotten, if i want all the consummation, not just for one vip customer, what to do???

Comment: @PapeMadialyDiaw: then we just annotate the `VipCustomer` queryset.

Comment: ok thanks!! ;) for your quick response , it helps a lot, thank you again